# ProgressBar doesn't appear with Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I've an issue with my ProgressBar and I hope you can help me to solve it.

I have layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".Edition">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
         ...../>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picEdition"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editionScroll"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tool_bar_edition" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/editionProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/editionScroll"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tool_bar_edition"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_info"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the part of the java code where I'm trying to call this ProgressBar is:

```
private ProgressBar editionProgressBar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edition);
        mContext = this;

    editionProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.editionProgressBar);

    previewLia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editionProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                try {
                    Bitmap confirmLiaBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getApplicationContext().openFileInput("editableImage"+i));
                    editImageView.setImageBitmap(doLiaFilter(confirmLiaBitmap));
                    i = i + 1;
                    try {
                        Bitmap finalLiaBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)editImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        finalLiaBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
                        FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput("editableImage"+i, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                        fo.close();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                editionProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
    });
}
```

But when I click on previewLia the ProgressBar doesn't appear... and it's so frustrating because in another activity where I'm using the same code into a Contraint Layout it's working perfectly.

Any idea where could be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try moving the progress bar out of the constraint layout to the coordinator layout. Just below the <include layout="@layout/activity_info"/>.

Comment: I'll try it! But in this case, how can I center the progress bar just in front of the ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem wasn't into the layout... it was into Java.

I solved the problem putting the setVisibility into an AsyncTask.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to keep it simple by using `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".Edition">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        ...../>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picEdition"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"/>

        <include layout="@layout/activity_info"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/editionProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```